# Why does memcpy need a const void pointer?

Tags: c

I wanted to use memcpy to do a 'type agnostic swap' in an array which might contain arbitrary types. Why does it require a const src pointer?

I wrote my own version instead:

```
void copyBytes(char *x, char *y, int howMany){
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i<howMany; i++){
    *(x+i) = *(y+i);
  }
}
```

Is there something wrong with my version?

Comment: `const *` isn't a restriction on `*`, it's a relaxation.

Comment: It doesn't *require* a `const` pointer - you can pass in non-const sources just fine. But because of that `const` modifier — basically a promise not to modify the source — you're *able* to pass in `const` sources, which would otherwise trigger warnings or errors, since the compiler would assume they might be modified.

Comment: A non-`const` pointer can be implicitly converted to a `const` pointer (`const` is a promise not to modify it), but the reverse is not possible. If the caller has a `const` pointer it means that it promised not to modify it, so, not to break this promise, changing it to a non-`const` pointer is not allowed.

Answer (score 9):

> Is there something wrong with my version?

I'd say so.  Here's a critique.

```
void copyBytes(char *x, char *y, int howMany)
```

First of all your pointers are `char *`, which means any pointer type other than `char *` needs to be explicitly converted.  You should be using `void *`, to which pointer types are implicitly converted.

```
uint16_t a, b;

copyBytes(&a, &b, sizeof(a));  // &a and &b are uint16_t*, not char*.
```

Second, the source, `y`, is not `const`, which means you will get warnings if you pass a `const` source.

```
char buf[512];
const char str[] = "Hello world";  // Contents of string are constant.
copyBytes(buf, str, sizeof(str));  // With your code, this produces a warning.
```

Third, `howMany` is signed, meaning you can pass a negative value.

I would recommend a signature like this (incidentally this is very similar to `memcpy`):

```
void copyBytes(void *x, const void *y, size_t howMany)
```

A fourth critique ... libc's `memcpy` is likely to be much better optimized, using larger-than-byte units, platform-specific performance tricks (example: inline assembly, SSE on x86), etc.  There's also `memmove` which has better specified behavior when the buffers overlap.

In conclusion: It's fine to write these routines yourself for learning purposes, but you're usually much better off with the C library.

Answer (score 6):

"Require"? "Require" is a wrong word. `memcpy` doesn't *require* a `const` src pointer. It *allows* a `const` src pointer. Allowing a `const` src pointer is a *weaker* specification then requiring a non-const src pointer. It *extends* the applicability of the function, not restricts it.

Requiring a non-const src pointer would restrict the applicability of `memcpy` - you wouldn't be able to pass pointers to `const` data to your function (unless you use an ugly cast). Why would you introduce such a requirement? `memcpy` does not modify the src data, so it is perfectly logical to *allows* constant data to be used as src for `memcpy`. This is why `memcpy` declares the src pointer as `const`.

The word "require" is actually applies to your version in this case. Your version *requires* non-const pointer as src pointer. And because of that additional (and completely unnecesary) requirement, your version is less applicable than `memcpy`. For example

```
const char src_data[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
char dst_data[3];

memcpy(dst_data, src_data, sizeof dst_data);    // Works
copyBytes(dst_data, src_data, sizeof dst_data); // Doesn't even compile
```

Answer (score 3):

Function `memcpy` doesn't modify source memory. That means it doesn't require a non-const pointer, it **allows** a const pointer as well as a non-const pointer. This is not a restriction on the parameter nor on the applicability of the function. You may pass any valid data pointer in there.

This is called an implicit conversion by compiler. In your particular case with `const` it is ["Qualification conversion"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast).

```
unqualified type can be converted to const
```

Opposite implicit conversion from a const pointer to a pointer is not allowed. Note word "*implicit*" here. That means `func(void *pointer)` is more restrictive than `func(void const *pointer)`.

If you omit `const` qualifier you leverage compiler imposed type safety. Compiler will warn you or others that it won't be a good idea to  pass a const pointer in.

If you use `const` qualifier in a function declaration you make a promise that you won't modify data there. This is a good hint to a programmer and improves readability of your code. However, this is a promise only. A bad function may violate the promise by casting out const-ness inside the function body. This is technically possible but bad.

Comment: Not quite any pointer. You may pass any pointer to an object to `memcpy`. Passing a pointer to a function to `memcpy` is not defined.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Well, yes. Then, in the same spirit, we need to say "any **valid** data pointer".